# Turning robot precisely

Tags: webots

I want to control a robot having differential wheels. Is it possible to turn a robot in certain degrees without encoders? How can I turn robot precisely in webots in certain degrees? For example 90 degrees or 20 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use encoders, an alternative would be to use an [InertialUnit](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/inertialunit), with this device you can get the yaw angle of the robot and use it to rotate of a precise amount of degrees.